# Commands URIs pass parameters

Tags: vscode-extensions

The following example. How to pass parameters to the corresponding command?

```js
const commentCommandUri = vscode.Uri.parse(`command:editor.action.addCommentLine`);
const contents = new vscode.MarkdownString(`[Add comment](${commentCommandUri})`);
contents.isTrusted = true;
```

Comment: The answer is where you got the code:  https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#command-uris

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `editor.action.addCommentLine` does not take any parameter. It simply comments the line that is selected currently in the editor (or the line where the cursor is positioned).

If you had another command that accepted arguments, then you could do something like this:

```js
...
const arguments = [arg1, arg2];
const myCommandUri = Uri.parse(`command:myCommand?${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arguments))}`);
contents.appendMarkdown(`[Do something](${myCommandUri})`);
```